# How do I correctly use Shared Preferences to store data in Android?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am making an app that calculates a persons BMI for a class and one of the requirements is that we use shared preferences to send the calculated BMI to a second activity. My problem is that while I'm not getting any errors on when I run the application, I don't think anything is sending over correctly.

Here is my main activity that runs on startup.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);

    final EditText Weight = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtWeight);
    final EditText Height = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtHeight);

    final SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class));

        //the bmi calculation
           // bmi = (weight * 703) / (height*height);
            bmi = weight * height;


            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
            editor.putInt("key1", weight);
            editor.putInt("key2", height);
            editor.putInt("key3", bmi);
            final boolean commit = editor.commit();

            }
        }
    );
}
```

Here is my second activity, that should display BMI sent over from the first activity.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);


    SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    int weight = sharedPref.getInt("key1", 0);
    int height = sharedPref.getInt("key2", 0);
    int bmi = sharedPref.getInt("key3", 0);

    TextView txtBmi = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtBmi);


    //error here
    txtBmi.setText(Integer.toString(bmi));
```

When my app gets to the second screen, the only thing that shows in the textview is a 0. If anyone could help me find my mistake that would be appreciated.

Comment: You are starting the second activity before storing the preferences...

Comment: Well, its best to make the keys constants so you don't typo them.  And to make the names meaningful rather than "key1", "key2"

Answer (score 5):

Note that you cannot load data before it is saved. In your code, you start the activity first **then** saving the data in SharedPreferences. This means that the second activity attempts to load data before it has even been saved.

More importantly, this is not the correct solution to your problem. SharedPreferences is intended to store data which should persist between uses of your app, for example a user name or game score. To pass data between activities, you should use the `Intent.putExtra()` method, instead.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue with your code is that you ar calling startActivity before saving the shared Preferences.
So,try change your code like this:

```
@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);

final EditText Weight = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtWeight);
final EditText Height = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtHeight);

final SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    //the bmi calculation
       // bmi = (weight * 703) / (height*height);
        bmi = weight * height;


        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putInt("key1", weight);
        editor.putInt("key2", height);
        editor.putInt("key3", bmi);
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class));

        }
    }
);
}
```